# DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, mariadb, dbi

When I do the query below from a mysql console it works fine but when I wrap into perl/DBI I get:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Unknown column 'AR_email' in 'field list'
```

Here is the query:

```
my $q = "SELECT SUBSTRING(AR_email, LOCATE('@', AR_email) + 1) AS domain  
         FROM carrier 
         WHERE AR_email IS NOT NULL 
         AND SUBSTRING(AR_email, LOCATE('@', AR_email) + 1) =?"; 
my $sth=$dbh->prepare($q);
$sth->execute($domain);
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is unintented *string interpolation*.

You are using double quotes (`"`) when assigning the query string to `$q`, but it contains an arobas (`@`), which is interpolated.

So `$q` actually ends up containing:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(AR_email, LOCATE(', AR_email) + 1) AS domain
FROM carrier
WHERE AR_email IS NOT NULL
AND SUBSTRING(AR_email, LOCATE(', AR_email) + 1) =?
```

If you were running this under `use warnings`, you would get this message:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @' in string
```

One way to solve this is to define the query as a litteral string, for example:

```
my $q = q/SELECT SUBSTRING(AR_email, LOCATE('@', AR_email) + 1) AS domain  
         FROM carrier 
         WHERE AR_email IS NOT NULL 
         AND SUBSTRING(AR_email, LOCATE('@', AR_email) + 1) =?/;
```

Moral of the story:

- use double quotes only when you *do* want string interpolation
- always `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Thank you very much for not only a correct but very instructive answer. The explanation will likely help prevent me from making a similar mistake in the future.

Comment: Another option (or in combination with single quotes/single `q`) is to specify the `@` string as a parameter like your `$domain`. `LOCATE(?, AR_email)` in both cases, then pass parameters `'@', '@', $domain` to execute.